# When can FOR be used as a preposition and a complementiser?

Tags: syntax, grammar

This question is based on several suppositions:

*For* as a preposition is able to be transformed into a wh- question with the wh- phrase preposed with *for*, as below with *senators John* acting as the complement:

1 (a) I will vote *for Senator John* in the election.
(b) *For which senator* will you vote in the elections?

However, in 2(a) below, *Senator John* only is not the complement of *for*.  Instead, *for* is a complementiser for the clause *Senator John to keep his cool*.  *Senator John* being the subject of the expression *to keep his cool*, the wh-expression can’t be preposed with *for*:

2 (a) They were anxious for *Senator John* to keep his cool.
(b) * For which senator were they anxious to keep his cool?

When *for* functions as a complement, the whole *for* clause can often be substituted with a *that* clause, but the **prepositional** *for* phrase can’t be replaced by a *that* clause:

3 (a) Is it really necessary *for there to be a showdown?*
(b) Is it really necessary *that there (should) be a showdown?*

4 (a) We are heading *for a general strike.*
(b) * We are heading *that there (will) be a general strike.*

Given the above, in which of the following sentences could *for*
be either a complementiser or a preposition:

A. The dog went straight *for* her throat.

B. It is important *for* parents to spend time with their children.

C. We are hoping *for* a peace agreement to be signed.

The expected answer is **B** because it passes both the preposing *wh-expression* with *for* test (For whom is it important to spend time with their children?) and the complementiser test of replacing *for* with *that* (It is important *that* parents spend time with their children.

My question is: Can anyone explain why **C** does not pass the preposition test?  It passes the complement test (We are hoping *that* a peace agreement be signed) but not the preposition test (For which agreement/what are we hoping to be signed?). Is this *for which* expression actually incorrect?

I have a bunch of ideas on this, but don’t to further muddle this already complicated post.

Thanks in advance for any contributions!!

Comment: I don’t really understand the question here. Neither B nor C can be turned into a _wh_-clause in a complementiser reading; the substitutions you give in parentheses are equally impossible for both. So the expected answer is that B and C are both complementisers. “For which agreement are we hoping to be signed?” is a question form of “We are hoping to be signed for [some] agreement” (e.g., as the band playing when the agreement is signed or something like that), which is an entirely different base sentence to start from – and one that clearly has a prepositional _for_. The same with B.

Comment: _Added:_ Oh, I see now. You’re asking in which sentences it’s possible for _for_ to be **either** preposition **or** complementiser. B would have to be the only answer there. The two uses would change the meaning (it’s important that parents spend time with their kids vs spending time with their kids is important to parents), but both readings are possible for the construction given. This is not the case with C. Was that what you were after?

Comment: Exactly! However, the question doesn’t reference meaning as part of the equation, rather that which is correct or possible.  Is it incorrect to say “For which agreement are we hoping to be signed?”.

Comment: No, I would say that’s a valid, if somewhat odd, sentence. If you replace _agreement_ with _event_, it becomes a perfectly natural sentence – the only oddity is that we don’t normally sign people for agreements.

Comment: So an explanation of B being the correct answer might be something along the lines of: Preposing the question *Which agreement are we hoping for to be signed?* (*For which agreement are we hoping to be signed?*) does not retain the original meaning of the sentence.

Comment: I’d say so, yes. B is ambiguous, and the two tests simply corresponds to the two different interpretations, while the preposition test for C yields a meaning that’s not possible in the original sentence, which implies that the _for_ can’t be a preposition there.

Comment: @Keelan Coming from the passive “to be signed”?

Comment: Because *for a peace agreement* is not a constituent!